# Android - how to customize tab text & indicator above ViewPager like this?

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I've googled so long but still not found a solution. 
I have a viewpager and want to have tabs and indicator set above the viewpager. 
However, I can't set multiple line text for tab text and can't set a customized view for the indicator.

[image]

I've tried using the default PagerTabStrip, unfortunately it can't achieve what I want as there is only a little customization allowed.

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pagerTabStrip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Can anyone give me a hint?